# How to find files created between hh:mm and HH:MM for any day?

Tags: linux, bash, find, time

For instance, find all files created between 20:00 and 23:30 for any day (not a specific day)?

been going through `man find` and didn't see anything that would do this.

Would I have to write my own script to parse create times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-newerXY` to find files between those times on a *specific* day, as in:

```
find -newermt "20150203 2000" -a \! \( -newermt "20150203 2330" \)
```

I've use the modification time because my ext4 file system does not hold creation times. If you have a file system which supports it, you can use `-newerBt`.

If you need to find files between those times on *any* day, then you need to run a script for each file in your `find` list. The easiest command for this would be `stat -c %y "$1"` and then extract and analyse the time field.

You could do arithmetic on the seconds of day `(($(stat -c %Y "$1") % 86400))`, checking it's between 72000 and 84600, but this would ignore summer time, identifying files modified between 21:00 and 00:30 during the summer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command below:

```
find . -mtime $(date +%s -d"Aug 10, 2013 23:30:00") -mtime $(date +%s -d"Aug 1, 2013 20:00:00")
```

or try this:

```
find /var/tmp -mtime +2 -a -mtime -8 -ls
```

to find files older than 2 days but not older than 8 days.